# End of season votes, determining a winner with multiple vote values

Tags: excel, list

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction..

I have a task to count the votes for an end of season award for a local sporting league. The problem is, there are 800 possible candidates for the award..

What we use is a 3, 2, 1 voting system and them add these all up to determine a winner.

I cant post an image to show exactly what it looks like...but I will try to make it look normal

```
T   U       V       W       X       Y       Z     AA
4   Name    Votes   Name    Votes   Name    Votes       
5   Mari    3       Mega    2       Eliza   1       
6   Lucy    3       Eliza   2       Jessi   1       
7   Meg     3       Jessi   2       Maria   1       
8   Eliza   3       Maria   2       Lucy    1       
9   Jessi   3       Lucy    2       Megan   1
```

Can anyone help?

What I am looking for is in column AA it would have the sum total of all the votes for Mari..  example  "Maria  6."

I have been tossing around a =sumproduct formula, but not sure if that would work..

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Fooz

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to cut columns W:X and Y:Z pasting them to the bottom of columns T:U and then use a pivot table as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Re-organize your results so all the names are in one columns and the votes are in another column:
2. Then place the name list in a third column:

[image]

For this data structure, in **D2** put the formula:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$16,C2,$B$2:$B$16)
```

and copy down

the highest score will be the winner.  If there is more than one person with the highest score, use another criteria for tie-breaking:

[image]